# Locale issue with Filter and request parameter in GWT Spring application

Tags: spring, gwt, filter

I have an issue with the Spring and GWT application I am working on. Initially when the application loads, I need to do some pre initializations for this and so I use a filter(DelegatingFilterProxy) for this purpose .

I am mapping this via the pattern /moduleName/* pattern

The issue I am facing is that lots of requests are coming in to this filter (From images , GWT rpc calls etc) and in some of these requests , the request parameter("locale") is getting lost .

The client may change the Language in between and I change my DB backend via abstactRoutingDatasource . Hence I need to keep trace of the request parameter . I tried storing the Locale in a session attribute but the whole code of tracking if there's a language change is getting messy .

The address bar URL in browser never changes  - This is just the request values which I need . Is there some header or some other route by which I can always track the changes in this URL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the url pattern to point directly to the jsp . This resolved the issue and I could isolate the parameters I required .